# response from website returns none with selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-crawler

I would like to download some data from national animal remedy dept. Since it's a dynamic website, i choose the selenium to do it. But it still returns none from the website. Could anyone help? thanks

website address : http://124.126.15.169:8081/cx/

the problem is that the url above stayed the same no matter which field i click in the left side of the tab.

[image]

I don't know how to construct a request url to the server so that i can get the json file in the response data.

Could anyone point out  how am I able to get the data?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Update the question exactly which step are you trying to _Automate_ through **tried the following code** as in `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#pageGrid')`

Comment: @DebanjanB question updated, thanks

Comment: `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#pageGrid')` refers to the grid-table, how can you download by clicking that? Moreover the element pointed in the snapshot is a **checkbox** how can clicking the element initiate download?